# Mp4 video rotation using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to rotate a Mp4 video by 90` clockwise, no need to change the format.  I have used following commands and got following issues:

ffmpeg -i input.mp4  -filter:v transpose=1 Output.mp4 **--** Video not shows, only audio does play.
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -crf 18.0 -vcodec libx264 -filter:v transpose=1 Output.mp4 **--**  Video not shows, only audio does play.
ffmpeg -i input.mp4  -vcodec mpeg4 -filter:v transpose=1 Output.mp4 **--** Quality degraded.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code:**

```
ffmpeg -i <input_video_filename> -vf "transpose=1" <output_video_filename>
```

**Transpose Parameters:**

```
0 = 90CounterCLockwise and Vertical Flip (default)
1 = 90Clockwise
2 = 90CounterClockwise
3 = 90Clockwise and Vertical Flip
```